# Nesting a post request inside a post request with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django Rest and JWT token based authentication.

I'm using a package called `djangorestframework_simplejwt`

I have my frontend UI created and successfully authenticating users.

I am having one issue, when I create a new user, I am sending the user back in the response data and then in a promise hitting the authentication endpoint to retrieve my tokens.

This doesn't feel right and feels like something that the backend can take care of entirely.

On the front end -

```
return APIUtil.signup(user).then((user) => {
  return APIUtil.authenticate(user.data)
}).then((user) => dispatch(authenticateUser(user)))

export const authenticate = (user) => {
  return axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/token/',
    data: {
      username: user.username,
      password: user.password
    }
  });
}

export const signup = (user) => {
  return axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/signup/',
      data: {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password,
        email: user.email
      }
  });
}
```

In my backend, I have a user viewset and serializer and with the django rest framework simple JWT package, I have the end point api/token/ which takes a user and returns their auth tokens.

I want to create the user and after creation, hit that endpoint on the backend, but I am not entirely sure the best way of doing this. I tried inheriting from the auth viewset in my user viewset, but wasn't successfully able to pass a post request to it.

Here is my user viewset

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = User
    queryset = model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    permission_classes = ([])
    authentication_classes = ([])

    def create(self, request, format=None):
        user = serializers.UserSerializer(data=request.data,context={'request': request})
        if user.is_valid():
            new_user = user.save()
            new_user.password = request.data['password']
            return Response({'username': new_user.username, 'password': new_user.password}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(user.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Thanks in advance for any help/direction.

Answer (score 0):

First, Please don't return the password in the response.

You don't need to hit the endpoint.

I guess that you want to return the auth token from the signup endpoint.

Just create a separate piece of code which you use in the /api/token to obtain a token.

And you can call that function inside your signup create to obtain the same token and you then return it in the response.